# The type or namespace name 'ServiceCollection' could not be found - Visual Studio Code

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make use of the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection package in Visual Studio Code, but I'm receiving the "type or namespace could not be found" error. This is a .NET 6 project, and I've double checked that the version of the DependencyInjection package I'm using (7.0) is compatible .NET 6 ([see here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/)). The only dependency listed on that same page is Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 7.0.0), which I also have added to the project.

I've searched every which way and can't find any solution that works for me. Here's what my .csproject file looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Discord.Net" Version="3.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0 />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: As you can see from the syntax highlighting, you're missing a `"` in the version attribute of the second PackageReference.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the syntax highlighting, you're missing a `"` in the version attribute of the second PackageReference:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="...DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0 />
```

Should be:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="...DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
```

(Where I abbreviated the include attribute value for brevity).

If that's somehow not the issue: Did you add a `using` statement?

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

Comment: I think the missing double quote may have just been from when I posted it here, I may have deleted it by accident. I was missing the using statement, but the reason I posted the question is that IntelliSense wasn't automatically recommending it when I tried. Good call out for anyone coming across this in the future, though!

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to have been resolved after restarting my computer.